# collection is not defined in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to get results from mongodb collection but when i call the function through routes it says the error collection is not defined,can any one suggest me help,

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("We are connected");

 }});

  exports.getprofile = function (url,req, res) {
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,res, docs) {
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    }else if(res.length){
      console.log(res)
      }
      else{
        console.log('no docs found');
      }
    res.send(res);
  });
}
```

Comment: You didn't define collection above the file but still want to access it

Comment: I think it should be `db.collection.find...`. Of course, it should be a real collection name.

Comment: Sergio,with added db.collection.find, it says db not found

Comment: @nlr_p: indeed, `db` is not visible at that point. You have it temporarily in that callback of `MongoClient.connect`, but you ignore it and not save anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here your not declared the variable(**collection**) so that only you got this error.You need to declare that variable with proper collection name.

**For Example :**
            If you are going to find the records in **users** collection under **test** schema  you need to the follow the below code.

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";
var collection = null;
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("We are connected");
    collection = db.collection('users');
 }});
        exports.getprofile = function (url,req, res) {
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,res, docs) {
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    }else if(res.length){
      console.log(res)
      }
      else{
        console.log('no docs found');
      }
    res.send(res);
  });
}
```

***Note*** : You Need Some Records in users collection under test schema.

Comment: Selva kumar,with your code i am getting error ,db is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the collection object first as mentioned below

```
  var collection = db.collection("simple_document_insert_collection_no_safe");
  // Insert a single document
  collection.insert({hello:'world_no_safe'});
```

Please refer the below link for more details.

[mongod db collection using nodejs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html)